# windows batch programming: Removing only exactly matching line from the file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file like this:

```
exit;
exit_cool
int exit =30
exitstatus;
exit ;
 exit;
some exit;
coolexit;
this line should not be removed.
exitexit;
```

I want to remove the line which contains only "exit;" from this file.So I want the command to remove only the first line from the file.I'm using this command currently:

```
type somefile.txt | find /v "exit;"
```

but the output I'm getting is:

```
exit_cool
int exit =30
exitstatus;
exit ;
this line should not be removed.
```

As you have seen the command removed all the lines containing `exit;`.I only want line 1 to be removed as it is the exact match.Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIND cannot do what you want. But FINDSTR can :-)

Using FINDSTR with regular expression anchors `^` for the beginning of a line, and `$` for the end of a line:

```
findstr /v "^exit;$" "somefile.txt"
```

Or using the `/x` option that has the exact same meaning, but can also be used with string literals, not just regular expressions:

```
findstr /v /x /c:"exit;" "somefile.txt"
```

Note that the end of line `$` anchor and `/x` option (and `/e` end option) only work properly when the text file uses Windows style lines that are terminated by carriage return/line feed. Unix style lines that end simply with line feed will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `findstr` command. instead of `find`
It is better and it takes regular expressions also.

```
type somefile | findstr /v "^exit;"
```

or

```
findstr /v "^exit;" somefile
```

good luck

Comment: Instead of solving the problem,your solution made the problem more intense.

Comment: The OP probably wants `findstr /v /b "exit;"` in order to remove only those lines where the string is found at the beginning of a line.